# can I force a failure when git merge found conflict or other issues?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to create a batch file that automatically merges a branch to master.
In my bat file, I have

```
git merge %1 -m "Merge to master [skip ci]"
```

To test my batch file, I passed a fake branch that doesn't exist and the output is

```
merge: test1 - not something we can merge
```

Then moved on to next command.

What I want is that if the merge doesn't work (either because the branch name is wrong or there is a conflict), the batch file should throw an error out and exit. So my azure devop pipeline will know that there is something wrong and it will fail the whole thing.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if it works for you but if something goes wrong with the merge, git's exit code _won't_ be 0. So, at least in bash, you can check what happened with it: `git merge blah; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo There was an error; exit 1; fi;`

Comment: hi, my batch will be run in a windows environment, are you sure $? work? Do I need to include something to make it work? Your idea sounds very great though

Comment: I guess you can adapt it to whatever environment you use. The exit code is pretty much supported anywhere you are making calls to processes, as in this case. And if this is bash, then sure, it doesn't matter that it runs on windows.

Comment: thanks, I worked it out now

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You can use environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` in windows system to check the return codes in the script commands.

> The environmental variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` contains the return code or the latest error level in the batch file, which is the latest error codes from the last command executed.

So you can add `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1` after the git merge command. See below:

```
git merge %1 -m "Merge to master [skip ci]"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B 1

... other commands
```

When above git merge commands failed, `%ERRORLEVEL%` value will not be 0, and the scripts will exit with code 1, which will fail your pipeline and the following scripts will not be executed.

Check out [this document](http://www.trytoprogram.com/batch-file-return-code/) for more information.

Comment: I currently have a solution similar to this, but then I hit a snag, the git merge that had found a conflict doesn't change the ERRORLEVEL. It kept on returning a 0... so my Azure Pipeline continued, and everything is green. Currently I'm trying to find a solution, but it would seem the solution would lie in git itself...will write my answer when I find it...